# Is it possible to unzip .ZIP file using .BAT command on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, zip, unzip, batch-processing

Is it possible to unzip .ZIP file using .BAT command on Windows XP? we have file.zip how to create a .BAT commands file to unzip\unpack it to some folder. USING ONLY NATIVE WINDOWS XP programms and commands.

So.. How to do such thing? (code example, please)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

But it involves using "scripting" and the use of [System.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28VS.85%29.aspx) (a good keyword). You should be able to use [cscript/WSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) which can run VBScript or JScript (WSH 5.6 comes with XP). The general idea is [here](http://www.naterice.com/blog/template_permalink.asp?id=64). There are some other interesting "issues" with this approach though; the operations runs asynchronously and the compression dialog box may appear -- *but it **can** be done using standard XP tools.*

I would recommend downloading [7-zip](http://7-zip.org). It is a 200~400k standalone command-line executable (depending on version), but it requires an initial "install" to grab the executable first. You don't need the GUI to run 7-zip.

Comment: I tried to use this solution (years ago), but the dialogs popping up (progress bar, blocking error messages) were just annoying. Command line utility is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Do you have XP? can you test this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874387/how-to-create-a-bat-file-to-download-and-unpack-a-zip-file/2875264#2875264 one?

Comment: @Ole Jak No XP now. I have done this years ago on XP/2k systems and more recently on Windows 7 with PowerShell (I don't know what I was thinking). See what devio said as it does apply -- and hence the recommendation to get a real utility. Happy ... coding?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.
Explanation: https://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no command line support for the native zip/unzip library that comes with windows XP. The only solution would be to use a uncompressing library.